# VUE3 how to check the ref of an element inside a template

Tags: vuejs3

I try to load a child component only when the parent `ref` is available.

```
<template>
  <div ref="refCurrentSlot" @mouseover="addCssClass" @mouseleave="removeCssClass">
    <div class="tooltipHolder"></div>
  </div>
    
  <Tooltip v-if="$refs.refCurrentSlot" :tooltip-holder="() => $refs.refCurrentSlot.querySelector('.tooltipHolder')"></Tooltip>
</template>
```

Because I need to pass the querySelector to the child, I added a `v-if`  directive

But before the component was mounted `$refs.refCurrentSlot` is undefined.
On `@mouseover` action, the component is updated, so `$refs.refCurrentSlot` is now available (but I need this before the first update)

I tried to use a computed property to get `$refs.refCurrentSlot` but it's never updating

```
<Tooltip v-if="refCurrentSlot" :tooltip-holder="() => refCurrentSlot.querySelector('.tooltipHolder')"></Tooltip>

...

computed: {
  refCurrentSlot() {
    console.debug('get it', this.$refs.refCurrentSlot) // this only logged before mount with undefined value
    return this.$refs.refCurrentSlot
  }
}
```

How to load child component only when the parent was rendered ? (`ref` is available) ?

Comment: the div and Tooltip don't have a parent/child relationship.  They're siblings.  Either way, passing a querySelector result as a prop doesn't pass a smell test.  Back up and explain what it is you're actually trying to do here. What functionality are you trying to create?  By being in the same component, the div and Tooltip component will by default either render or not render together. There's no way given the code so far why one would render (or not render) without the other doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related to reactivity, because $refs is not reactive. You can find the description in the [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html#ref).

There it's written that:

> this.$refs is also non-reactive, therefore you should not attempt to use it in templates for data-binding.

I got your code working but it still is a bit confusing. The v-if on the tooltip does not make sense, because the ref will always be set when the component was mounted. Also i dont understand why you're searching the tooltipHolder with a query selector. You could instead set the ref directly to the tooltipHolder.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {computed, ref} from 'vue'
const refCurrentSlot = ref<HTMLDivElement>()

const toolTipHolder = computed(()=>{
  return refCurrentSlot.value?.querySelector('.tooltipHolder')
})

const addCssClass = ()=>{
  //Your code here
}

const removeCssClass = ()=>{
  //Your code here
}
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="refCurrentSlot" @mouseover="addCssClass" @mouseleave="removeCssClass">
    <div class="tooltipHolder"></div>
  </div>
  <Tooltip v-if="refCurrentSlot" :tooltip-holder="toolTipHolder"></Tooltip>
</template>
```

Comment: I was unable to implement this way of doing things.
By the way, for mounted, it works as intended.

Thanks for giving some hints
<Tooltip v-if="tooltipHelper" :tooltip-holder="tooltipHelper"></Tooltip>

 mounted() {
    this.tooltipHelper = this.$refs. refCurrentSlot.querySelector(". tooltipHolder")
  },